# How do add an icon or image to your application in application builder

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How do I add an icon to my finished application in apex 4.2.6 .. Not seen this in any of the books..in both desktop and J-query mobile UIs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the icons very easily. These application icons are some background images that are displayed using the CSS Sprite technique. 
For each of the app report it's generated a class attribute from internal packaged app metadata. 
That is the way to control which icon is displayed from those available in the sprite image.

Take a look at this [discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2509152) on Oracle community.

Comment: Thanks Boss. Is there a way to add a relationship between tables after the tables columns have been created (i.e apart from during the "foreign key referencing" stage in during table creation )

Comment: It depends what exactly you want to do.